# Как узнать дату через ровно через 14 недель?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Как узнать дату в SQL которая будет через 14 недель?

Знаю что есть что-то типа такого

```
select DATEPART( wk, GETDATE()) as CurWeek,
       DATEPART( wk, GETDATE() + 98) as FutureWeek
```

однако, тут я получаю только неделю.

Comment: Какая СУБД? Способы работы с датами и временем у каждой свои.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Microsoft SQL Server 2016

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте [DATEADD](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

```
select DATEPART(wk, GETDATE()) as CurWeek,
       DATEPART(wk, DATEADD(wk, 14, GETDATE())) as FutureWeek
```

Чтобы узнать дату через 14 недель, а не номер недели:

```
select DATEADD(wk, 14, GETDATE()) as FutureDate
```

Comment: а как получить не неделю, а дату, через 14 недель?

Comment: Вместо wk использовать day и month

Comment: select DATEADD(wk, 14, GETDATE()) as FutureDate